# Convert SQL Server DATETIMEOFFSET to mySQL DateTime

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis

I've been tasked to write an SSIS package to convert several SQL Server databases to mySQL and my current issue issue is with the DATETIMEOFFSET datatype from SQL Server.
I've tried casting the field, I've tried converting it and I've tried casting it *then* converting it to a DATETIME datatype but no luck.  But everything I've tried has resulted in this error:

> [ADO NET Destination [2]] Error: An exception has occurred during data insertion, the message returned from the provider is: ERROR [07006] [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(a) Driver][mysqld-5.6.10]Conversion is not supported

Any ideas on how to get this sql server datatype into mySql?

Answer (score 2):

Converting using almost any style will cause the datetime2 value to be converted to 
UTC.
Also, conversion from datetime2 to datetimeoffset simply sets the offset at +00:00, 
per the below, so it is a quick way to convert from Datetimeoffset(offset!=0) to 
Datetimeoffset(+00:00)

```
declare @createdon datetimeoffset
set @createdon = '2008-12-19 17:30:09.1234567 +11:00'

select CONVERT(datetime2, @createdon, 1)
--Output: 2008-12-19 06:30:09.12

select convert(datetimeoffset,CONVERT(datetime2, @createdon, 1))
--Output: 2008-12-19 06:30:09.1234567 +00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the DATETIMEOFFSET TO a DATETIME type using the following derived column:

```
DATEADD("hh", DATEDIFF("hh",((DT_DBTIMESTAMP)[DataColumn]), [DataColumn]), ((DT_DBTIMESTAMP)[DataColumn]))
```

For more details check the following article:

- [SSIS Convert between datetimeoffset and datetime](http://ntsblog.homedev.com.au/index.php/2014/06/11/ssis-convert-datetimeoffset-datetime/)